# Displaying edited row of one DataGridView in other DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

How do I display an edited row of a data grid to another data grid? Suppose data grid 1 contains some details. When I make any changes to any row, that entire row should display on other data grid. The code must be in cell value changed?

This is the current code:

```
dgvinvtrylast.Rows.Add();
for (int i = 0; i < dgvinventory.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
{
    dgvinvtrylast.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
    dgvinvtrylast.Columns[2].ReadOnly = true;
    dgvinvtrylast.Columns[3].ReadOnly = true;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgvinventory.Rows)
    {
        dgvinvtrylast.Rows.Add(); dgvinvtrylast.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value =
            dgvinventory.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
        dgvinvtrylast.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value =
            dgvinventory.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
        dgvinvtrylast.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value =
            dgvinventory.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: dgvinvtrylast.Rows.Add();
 for (int i = 0; i < dgvinventory.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
{{ dgvinvtrylast.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
dgvinvtrylast.Columns[2].ReadOnly = true;
dgvinvtrylast.Columns[3].ReadOnly = true;
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgvinventory.Rows)
{dgvinvtrylast.Rows.Add();
dgvinvtrylast.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dgvinventory.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
dgvinvtrylast.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dgvinventory.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
dgvinvtrylast.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = dgvinventory.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
}}} this is my current code

Comment: Are the `dataGridView`'s bound?

Comment: yes.the code is in 3 tier architecture.data access layer contains the Sql code for filling the data grid